# Lambda expression in 'if' statement condition

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I am new to C#, but from my understanding this code should work. Why doesn't it work?

This is an example of my code.

```
List<Car> cars // This has many cars initialized in it already
if (() => {
   foreach(Car car in cars){
       if (car.door == null) return true;
   }
}){then .......}
```

Simply put, all I want the code to do is run the `if` statement if any car does not have a door.

After trying to compile I get this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: You're not even using the correct lambda syntax. It would be `() => {`..., not `()={`... Of course, it wouldn't work if you *were* using it, but that's another story.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to check if any car does not have a door then simply use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - it determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition:

```
if (cars.Any(c => c.door == null))
   // then ...
```

---

Just for fun: you should execute lambda to get boolean result in if condition (but for this case use Any)

```
Func<bool> anyCarDoesNotHaveDoor = () => { 
    foreach(var car in cars)
       if (car.door == null)
           return true;
    return false; 
};

if (anyCarDoesNotHaveDoor())
   // then ...
```

I introduced local variable to make things more clear. But of course you can make this puzzle more complicated

```
 if (new Func<bool>(() => { 
        foreach(var car in cars)
           if (car.door == null)
               return true;
        return false; })())
    // then ...
```

Comment: Just to make sure could you have done this.  if (Func<bool>() => {})

Comment: @user3813249, You still have to call the delegate. A delegate in and of itself makes no sense to an `if` statement.

Comment: @user3813249 Func<bool> delegate should return boolean value, so you can't just assign empty body to it, like you can do with `Action`

Answer (score 9):

Well, the error says it all. An `if` statement is expecting a *boolean expression* which a delegate is not. If you were to call the delegate (assuming it returned a `bool`), you would be fine. However, `if` does not know to call it.

The easy way to do this is with the `Any` LINQ extension method:

```
if (cars.Any(car => car.door == null))
```

The `Any` method knows to actually invoke the lambda expression on each member of the collection, and returns a `bool`. This makes it a valid boolean expression for the `if` statement.

Comment: This seems a misleading explanation. A delegate *is* an expression, as evidenced by your calling it a lambda expression a moment later; it's just that `if` demands its condition be a *Boolean* expression - one of type `bool`. Lambdas are of type `Func<T>` for some return type `T` and hence can't satisfy that requirement. (They can also be expression-tree types, depending on inference from the context of their use, but they can't be `bool`.)

Comment: @00Davo You are correct, that could have been worded better. I'll edit and see if I can clear it up.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to actually do something to cars without doors:

```
foreach (var car in cars.Where(car => car.door == null)) {
    car.door = <whatever>;
}
```